# Can AWS IAM roles be used for app running outside AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, heroku, amazon-iam

So I think that the simplest solution is my problem is to use AWS for everything but I wanted to understand what is possible:

I understand that IAM roles can be associated with an AWS service such as EC2 or Lambda so that an application/function running within that service can retrieve credentials to sign API requests to other AWS services.
I have a previous application running on Heroku and using Amazon S3. Currently I have an IAM user set up for this application which signs requests to the AWS API using the access keys associated with the IAM user account. I think that best practice is to use an IAM role rather than a user for application source code AWS API calls, however is it possible to set this up for the application hosted outside of AWS or would I need to migrate the application to AWS EC2 in order to use IAM roles?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter where the application is hosted but to assume an IAM role you will need IAM credentials (chicken and egg). Typically you would design a secure way for your app to retrieve these base credentials. This is one disadvantage of running your compute outside of AWS (because it can't automatically assume an IAM role).

One option would be to create an IAM user whose only permissions were to be able to assume a given IAM role. Supply those IAM user credentials to your application, outside of AWS, securely and have the application assume the IAM role, ideally with an `ExternalId` that itself is also securely stored and securely retrieved by your application. Additionally, you can [manage access to the IAM role](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/), for example defining which principals can assume the role, and under which conditions.

Comment: Thank you. So if the compute instance is inside of AWS it can pick up IAM credentials automatically  and assume an IAM role, but if it is outside the application needs to be supplied with IAM user credentials for example by environment/config variables? Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Yes. All compute launched in AWS can be configured to allow the launching AWS service to assume the IAM role on your behalf (that's why IAM roles require a trust policy which says which principals, e.g. AWS services, can assume the role). Outside of AWS, you need a way for your app to get IAM credentials (or you would need to proxy your app's requests through an AWS-hosted compute API that can therefore assume the role and proxy the relevant AWS API calls). See [Requesting temporary security credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_request.html).

Answer (score 1):

AWS announced a new feature AWS IAM Anywhere that should help if you need to avoid using access/secret keys. It's more complicated but follows security best practices.

> AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) now enables workloads that
> run outside of AWS to access AWS resources using IAM Roles Anywhere.
> IAM Roles Anywhere allows your workloads such as servers, containers,
> and applications to use X.509 digital certificates to obtain temporary
> AWS credentials and use the same IAM roles and policies that you have
> configured for your AWS workloads to access AWS resources.

and more here:

> create a trust anchor where you either reference your AWS
> Certificate Manager Private Certificate Authority (ACM Private CA) or
> register your own certificate authorities (CAs) with IAM Roles
> Anywhere. By adding one or more roles to a profile and enabling IAM
> Roles Anywhere to assume these roles, your applications can now use
> the client certificate issued by your CAs to make secure requests to
> AWS and get temporary credentials to access the AWS environment.

AWS Announcement: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/07/aws-identity-access-management-iam-roles-anywhere-workloads-outside-aws/

User Guide:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rolesanywhere/latest/userguide/introduction.html

Answer (score 0):

From [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3#credentials):

> Because of the sensitive nature of your S3 credentials, you should never commit them to version control. Instead, set them as the values of config vars for the Heroku apps that will use them.

> Use the `heroku config:set` to set both keys

```
heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=xxx AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=yyy
Adding config vars and restarting app... done, v21
  AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID     => xxx
  AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY => yyy
```

---

The above is in line with AWS's own best practices for managing AWS access keys, specifically [not embedding access keys directly in code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-access-keys-best-practices.html#iam-user-access-keys).

You can't use IAM roles in the sense that it is picked up automatically by AWS, outside of AWS, without specifying credentials specifically.

Your next best option is environment variables (as detailed above), specifying the access key ID and secret access key for a user with a role [granting the least privilege](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) required for the files they need to read from S3 e.g. specific bucket name, specific files, even [specific IP addresses](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/iam-restrict-calls-ip-addresses/) if possible, etc.